# How get the data of the nested JSON object MongoDB with node.js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a JSON object on MongoDB

[image: picture]

I can`t understand how to get Products by ID from the Menu?

Answer (score 0):

You can read that by using the following command. 
To read a single data from array:

```
db.dbname.findOne({'products': 
     {$elemMatch:{
          '_id': id_of_the_product_you_want_to_read
           }
     }})
```

You can change the parameters **_id** to the necessary parameter you want.